# How to get all possible values of an enum in java? (not knowing the specific Enum)

Tags: java, enums

I'd like to create a JComboBox that handles the selection of any Enum given to it. For that I need a method to retrieve all the available values of the Enum passed to the JComboBox. As I don't know the specific Enum I can't call `EnumType.values()`.
I could think of some complicated solutions where supported Enums would have to implement some interface I define, but I guess I am missing a simpler, more general solution. What is the way I should go?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[`Class.getEnumConstants()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29)

Comment: how about `ENUMClass.values()`?